# Reading a File from HDFS, Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

**I am trying to read a file from HDFS but I am having a problem here. The file couldn't exists so for that reason I have to check if exists. If the file exists I read that file, otherwise I read an empty DF**.

So what I am trying is:

```
val fs: FilySystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(path), new Configuration())
if (fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(s"$Path"))) {
    val df6 = spark.read.parquet(path)
} else {
    val df6 = df1.limit(0)
}
val df6.show()
```

But I am getting the following error on Jupyter:

```
Message: <console>:28: error: not found: type FileSystem
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you import filesystem? `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (with your adjustment) -

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import java.net.URI
import scala.io.Source
    
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://cluster:8020/"), new Configuration())
val path = new Path("/HDFS/FILE/LOCATION")
val stream = hdfs.open(path)
val temp = Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines()
```